# What happens if I restart a MariaDB server while it is Repairing or Optimizing a very large table?

Tags: optimization, mariadb, database-performance

What happens if I restart a MariaDB server while it is Repairing or Optimizing a very large table (like at least 20GB)? Probably because I need to use the table for other stuff and I'm just getting plain bored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REPAIR` and `OPTIMIZE` are designed to be crash-safe.  (Or at least to a large extent.)

`OPTIMIZE`, for example, copies the table over to a tmp table name.  When finished, it internally does a `RENAME TABLE`, which is fast.

`OPTIMIZE` is needed in only very rare cases for MyISAM.  It is even less needed for InnoDB.  What is your use case?  I will probably counter that it is 'futile' or 'not worth the effort'.

Repair is needed only for MyISAM.  I hope you are not using that antiquated engine.

**More**

- Consider switching to InnoDB; we can discuss this further.  `REPAIR` is much less often needed, plus is automated.
- What is the schema?  What is the data flow like?  I may have tips on avoiding the indexes getting out of date.  (The way the .MYD file is laid out is problematic for *certain* data flows.)
- Use `ANALYZE TABLE` (instead) when there is no complaint about index corruption yet queries are suddenly slow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rick. You are right about Optimize. In my case it is not that useful, but Repair is. My case being, I have very large MyISAM tables which periodically need to be repaired because over time queries become extremely slow and I get a notification in PHPMyAdmin telling me to repair the table. When I do repair the table, it takes about half an hour for a 10GB table, but the query time does come down considerably after repair. However, tables bigger than 20GB often take about 2 hours to repair, and sometimes I need to interrupt the process, but I've never actually done it.

Comment: See my added comments.

Comment: I normally use InnoDB where I have control over technology decisions, because I love row-level-locking, however, in my current situation, row-level-locking corrupts table data because of really bad-written business logic. And it is a huge system so I can't just rewrite some of the logic to incorporate InnoDB.

Comment: @Turab - You may have to 'bite the bullet' if the business logic is so broken that it corrupts in MyISAM.